# Angular ng2-charts mixed chart x axis problem

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

in my example im using Angular 15.2.4 and ng2-charts version 4.1.1 with chart.js 4.2.1

im trying to figure out an effective method how to draw a line chart over a bar chart. It should go uninterrupted through the whole diagram, starting at x=0 to x=max and not be interrupted as in my result

Heres a screenshot of what i mean:

[image: Example1]

Heres how it looks instead:

[image]

I have found a solution on Stackoverflow with making placeholders at the beginning and at the end with empty data values, but some how it doesn't seem to work in my case.

Theres also an option with `beginAtZero: true` but i've tried it in a different example it doesnt quite work that way i wanted it to.
Heres the result:

[image]

Heres my Mixed Chart Component:

```
export class MixedChartComponent {
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective | undefined;

  public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {},
      y: {
        min: 10
      }
    },
  };
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';

  public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: [ '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012' ],
    datasets: [
    ]
  };

  data = [
    {
      "val1": 65,
      "val2": 50
    },
    {
      "val1": 59,
      "val2": 50
    },
    {
      "val1": 80,
      "val2": 50
    },
    {
      "val1": 81,
      "val2": 50
    },
    {
      "val1": 56,
      "val2": 50
    },
    {
      "val1": 55,
      "val2": 50
    },
    {
      "val1": 40,
      "val2": 50
    },
  ]

  setData() {

    let data_value1: any[] = [];
    let data_value2: any[] = [];

    this.data.forEach((entry) => {
      data_value1.push(entry['val1']);
      data_value2.push(entry['val2']);
    });

    let dataset1 : any = {
      data: data_value1,
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Series A',
      barThickness: 35,
      borderRadius: 30,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(88,84,247,0.5)'
    }
    let dataset2 : any = {
      data: data_value2,
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Series B',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(176,195,230,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(176,195,230,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      fill: 'origin',
    }

    this.barChartData.datasets.push(dataset1);
    this.barChartData.datasets.push(dataset2);

  }

  constructor() {
    this.setData();
  }
}
```

If needed i can provide a Stackblitz example of my case.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: These off-site images make the question harder to understand; could you please use the "embed image" tool in the editor to upload the images to Stack Overflow's own image hosting?

Comment: @tripleee sorry, i didn't knew this feature existed. thank you for the advice!